# Array of arrays systemverilog

Tags: arrays, system-verilog

I have a list of array which are defined so:

```
bit [2:0] Param1[8];
.
.
bit [2:0] Param16[8];
```

I want to create a list of these array in order to iterarte over them:

```
bit [2:0] array[16][8] = {Param1, Param2 ... Param16};
```

but when I try to write 3 bit long bits to every array inside this array I get false results. What am I missing?

Comment: you assumed invalid order of indexes in this case. I guess you meant `bit[2:0] array[8][16]`

Comment: You need to clarify the results you are expecting with the results you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate through a multi-dimensional array to assign values to it.

The following code will not work as it has following to issues:

1. It will create an array of 16rows and 8columns whereas you need an array of 8rows and 16columns.
2. It will expect a 3bit value to be assigned to array element [8][16].

The following code might help to achieve the functionality you intend:

```
module test();

bit [2:0] Param1[8];
bit [2:0] Param2[8];
bit [2:0] Param3[8];
bit [2:0] Param4[8];
bit [2:0] Param5[8];
bit [2:0] Param6[8];

int i=0;
int j=0;

bit [2:0] array [8][6];

initial begin
  array[0][0] = 'd1;
  array[0][1] = 'd1;
  array[0][2] = 'd1;

foreach(array[i,j])
  $display("array[%0d][%0d] = %0d",i,j,array[i][j]);

for(i=0;i<6;i++)
  array[0][i] = Param1[i];

foreach(array[i,j])
  $display("array[%0d][%0d] = %0d",i,j,array[i][j]);

end

endmodule
```

Please find the link to run the code [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/5Ce3).